# How to separate two transactions calling each other in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a call from transaction A to transaction B and transaction B fails, how to rollback only in transaction B but not in transaction A

```
@Autowired
ResourceServiceImpl resourceService;
// transaction A
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
void syncRestApi() {
    for (RoleResourceRelation roleResourceRelation : roleResourceRelations) {
        roleResourceRelationMapper.save(roleResourceRelation);
    }
   //call transaction B
    try {
        resourceService.test();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


@Service
@Transactional
public class ResourceServiceImpl {

  //transaction B
  public void test(){
    throw new RuntimeException("");
  }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing a RuntimeException in B that will cause the transaction of A rollback.

So you have to catch this Exception in A or you have to configure RuntimeException to not rollback (noRollbackFor), but this will not be a good idea because this may lead to problems.

Comment: i tried as you instructed but i still get the message "  Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only", i updated my code again

Comment: if i add Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW to B the problem is solved, however since B is shared i cannot do it

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add REQURIES_NEW. If it's shared should the transactional behavoir different in the other case